# Error: insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, timeout, buffering

I am at the very beginning of learning Mongoose, and I am having trouble saving this model to my database and keep getting an error:
insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

This is my code:

[image: Code]

How can I find a solution for this?

Comment: Could you replace the image of the code you have supplied with text? Images of text don't work well with clipboards, screen-readers, and search engine robots. A code formatting tool is supplied in the editor. You can [edit the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71983430/edit).

Comment: I would guess that on the connect and save operations, you either need to add a success callback, a thenable, or an await. What documentation are you working from?

Comment: Please add your code as code blocks not screenshots

Comment: You are trying to save the document before the connection to the DB has been established, if you'd move that part of the code to the "then" block after the connection is completed you will see that it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
const options = {
  autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
  maxPoolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
  family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
};
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).